# column wise addition in tableau worksheet

Tags: tableau-api

[image]

I have made this tableau Worksheet. All columns are derived using calculated field. Based on resource I am calculating all attributes.

Please help me to add all values column wise in same worksheet .
I tried using  "total" available in analytics pane but its not working in this case .

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

The way this is set up, which each column being a calculated field, to sum them also requires a calculated field.

```
[ColumnA]+[ColumnB]+[ColumnC]+etc
```

Adding Totals to the table won't work in this case, as you have discovered.